# como validar para que los objetos creados por un usuario se muestren solo para él

Tags: django

en mi app necesito que se muestren solo las cosas que ha creado un usuario cualquiera.Lo ilustro con un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

code:

```
<h1>Mis Eventos</h1>
<p>
   <a href="{% url "crear_evento" %}">Agregar Evento</a>
</p>
<ul>

{% for evento in evento_list %}
    <li>
        <p>{{ evento.nombre|upper }}</p>
        <p>
            <a href="#">Ver</a> | 
            <a href="{% url "editar_evento" evento.id %}">Editar</a> | 
            <a href="{% url "eliminar_evento" evento.id %}">Borrar</a> 
        </p>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>   
<h1>¡No tienes eventos! :(</h1>
<a href="#">Volver</a>
```

## así como ésta muestra todos los objetos de la base de datos.

Comment: Añade algo de código, siempre es mejor código que imágenes...

Answer (score 2):

deberías tener un atributo en tu modelo `evento`  `"usuario_creador" (ForeingKey a User)`, que almacene dicho usuario en el momento de guardar un evento en base de datos.

A la hora de rescatar el listado, debes asegurarte de tener una queryset, que filtre solo los eventos que hayan sido creados por el usuario que tienes en sesión.

```
current_user = request.user
eventos_usuario = eventos.objects.filter(usuario_creador=current_user)
```

Un saludo.